# Using Bitbucket Pipeline Branch Trigger to Update Source on Another Server

Tags: powershell, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to wrap my head around what I need to do to accomplish the title of this post.  I have automation scripts on a server (JAMS Scheduler) and a copy of their source code is stored in Bitbucket. I want to trigger a pipeline when code is pushed to the master branch (each file in the repo is a separate .ps1 script so I match by script name to what is on the automation server for update) and then update the script on the server where automation occurs.  I have written a Powershell script that accesses my automation server and will include the Bitbucket access as well.  Is the purpose of the Docker image to "run" my Powershell script?  I am new to all of this and am looking for any direction one can provide please.  It seems all the documentation that I am reading has to do more with CI and delivering a production build somewhere.

Here is my yaml file so far:

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/powershell:latest

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          script:
            - echo "This script runs only on commit to the master branch"
```